# Fourier series with general formula

Tags: fourier-series, fourier-transform

I have this graph with a Fourier series, but I don't know how to resolve this with the general function

$$
X(t) = \frac{a_0} 2 + \sum_{i=1}^n a_n \cos(n\omega t) + \sum_{i=1}^n b_n \sin(n\omega t) $$

[image: Fourier serie]

Comment: is this the graph of $f$ you are trying to find the Fourier series of?

Comment: @gt6989b Yes, I don't know how to do this graph easier, I think is the best way for resolve this

Comment: @Draggluon You just have to compute integrals to determine $a_0$, $a_n$ and $b_n$. Also, the Fourier series expression you gave is wrong. The correct expression is $$f(x) =\frac{a_0}{2}+\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} a_n \cos\left(\frac{2\pi n x}{T}\right) + \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} b_n \sin\left(\frac{2\pi n x}{T}\right),$$ where $T$ is the period of the function $f(x)$.

Comment: Note that in English, unlike French, the noun "series" is either singular or plural, so that one refers to "a series", no to "a serie". I edited accordingly. $\qquad$

Comment: What's the formula to compute the coefficients ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust I calculate $$ a_n = \frac 2 {T} \int f(t) cos (nwt) dt $$ and  $$ b_n = \frac 2 {T} \int f(t) sen(nwt) dt $$

Comment: Is your question how to apply the formulas to compute the integrals ? Split in subintervals.

Comment: @YvesDaoust How many subintervals we have? 3?

Comment: @Draggluon: I see $8$ of them.

Comment: @YvesDaoust It not would be .. ? $$  f(x)= \left\{ \begin{array}{lcc}
             A &   if & 0 < t < \pi \\
             \\ -A &  if & \pi < t < 2\pi \\
             \\ -2A &  if & 2\pi <t < 3\pi
             \end{array}
   \right.$$ For a period

Comment: @Draggluon: why do you drop the remaining ? (By the way it is unclear what the period is.)

Comment: @YvesDaoust I failed, there are more subintervals, but not $ 8 $ I count $4$, the period is $5\pi $, I don't know if it's correct

Comment: @Draggluon: you can't tell from the plot. $5\pi$ or $8\pi$ are possible. But not $4$.